# Google Cloud Client Libraries and Google APIs Client Libraries

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Client Libraries and Google APIs Client Libraries

Both of them shared some same code base. And Google documentation suggested that if the "Google Cloud Client Libraries" that we are looking for is not available, then search "Google APIs Client Libraries".

So what is the relationship between Google Cloud Client Libraries and Google APIs Client Libraries?

Is Google Cloud Client Libraries "new version" (upgraded, refined, systemized) of "Google APIs Client Libraries"?

Is "Google APIs Client Libraries" phasing out and going to be replaced by "Google Cloud Client Libraries" totally later on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this page](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) on the GCP website which gives a nice overview and current coverage of the two different sets of libraries.

Google Cloud Client Libraries are indeed newer than the API Clients.  They are Google's latest client library offering and aim to provide the best possible, idiomatic surface for Google's Cloud APIs.

The new library model builds on the experience of its predecessor but is essentially a ground up effort.

The API client libraries are mature and continue to be supported in parallel.  We don't expect to add any more major features but definitely we will continue to support these libraries, fix bugs, and add minor features as required to support ongoing changes.

Hope this is helpful!